# How to efficiently wait for a linked file to finish running before continuing with script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I'm adding elements to index.php through a foreach loop in a file called ajaxLoad.php, that's loaded using jQuery's load().

The problem is that jQuery can't find those elements when I try to select them. I know that ajaxLoad.php hasn't finished printing out messages. When I try to select the delete class anchors with jQuery, jQuery can't find them.

```
            <div class="messages">

                <!--these are added by the foreach loop-->
                <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>

            </div>
```

A probably important note is that the delete class is not in the index.php markup, they're only added through load(). Here is the inline jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function(){

    //adds messages to a div
    $('.messages').load('ajaxLoad.php');

    //later on...
    $('.delete').click(function(){
        alert('Hey');
        //nothing happens
    });

});
</script>
```

I've looked into $(window).load(function(){}) but it doesn't seem to work.
I would be glad for help! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in the callback function, see the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('.messages').load('ajaxLoad.php', function() {
    $('.delete').click(function(){
        alert('Hey');
    });
});
```

Or use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('.messages').load('ajaxLoad.php');

//later on...
$('body').on('click', '.delete', function() {
// ^^^^ any containing element that is already there on page-load
    alert('Hey');
});
```

Comment: Well, that was a lot easier than expected xD
It worked perfectly! Thanks a lot! It said I can accept the answer in 5 min so I'll accept it then :)